# How to get the screen height and adjust view to fit proportionately

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I have a requirement where i need to add multiple views to a screen with only top and bottom padding as 10. The first view which is a banner should occupy one third of the screen, while the rest 3 view should fill the entire screen with proportionate heights of each. How can i dynamically calculate the screen height and adjust my view accordingly.

Comment: you dont need to calculate screen height. you can use `layout_weight`

Comment: can you share your xml code?

Comment: when you say proportionately, do you know the proportions beforehand (i.e. static) or will it depend on the views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can follow this example code to modify your own code.

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:circular="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_simple"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    tools:context="com.batterysaver.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <com.lylc.widget.circularprogressbar.CircularProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/battery_percentage"
                    style="@style/Widget.ProgressBar.Holo.CircularProgressBar"
                    android:layout_width="110dip"
                    android:layout_height="110dip"
                    circular:cpb_subtitle="Battery"
                    circular:cpb_title="Title" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/optimize_Button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/save_power" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/panel"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/temp_degree"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/voltage_meter"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/level_value"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/temp_text"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center|top"
                    android:text="Temp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/voltage_text"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center|top"
                    android:text="Voltage"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/level_text"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center|top"
                    android:text="Level"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/wifi_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="10dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/blutooth_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="10dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/brightness_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_light_normal" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/rotate_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_rotate_normal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mode_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_sound_normal" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/screen_timout_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_timeout" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/location_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_location_normal" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sync_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_saintic_normal" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/flightmode_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_airplanmode_normal" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mobiledata_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_data_normal" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your parent layout is LinearLayout,
Set the banner's properties as

```
layout_height="0dp"
layout_weight="3"
```

For each of the remaining 3 views, set properties as

```
layout_height="0dp"
layout_weight="2"
```

Doing this will make sure the banner has 1/3rd of the screen height, and the remaining 3 views are proportionately sized.
(This answer is not to find Height of screen dynamically. But based on your question, it looks like this is what you wanted to acheive.)